Check if keys of Object B existing within Object A exist within another array value of a key in Object A
Example code:
enum ENUM_A { 
  ONE="ONE",
  TWO="TWO",
  THREE="THREE",
  FOUR="FOUR"
}

interface TYPE_A {
  myArray: ENUM_A[],
  mySpecificMapping: {
    [key in ENUM_A]?: boolean
  }
}
const myObject: TYPE_A = {
  myArray: [ENUM_A.ONE, ENUM_A.THREE],
  mySpecificMapping: {
    [ENUM_A.ONE]: true,
    // Uncommenting the line below should result in a TypeScript error
    // [ENUM_A.TWO]: true,
    [ENUM_A.THREE]: true,
    // Uncommenting the line below should result in a TypeScript error
    // [ENUM_A.FOUR]: true,
  }
}


myObject should error if "mySpecificMapping" contains keys that don't exist within "myArray"
I think I need to use self referencing types here?

You need a generic type (well, it could be a union but that would scale very badly with the size of EnumA) and a helper function as shown in this playground link. Does that meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

I'll write an answer when I get a chance.

Yes, for this to work you need TypeA to be generic in the EnumA members that are actually present in myArray, like this:
interface TypeA<T extends EnumA> {
  myArray: T[],
  mySpecificMapping: {
    [K in T]?: boolean
  }
}

Then you could change the annotation to
const myObject: TypeA<EnumA.ONE | EnumA.THREE> = {
  myArray: [EnumA.ONE, EnumA.THREE],
  mySpecificMapping: {
    [EnumA.ONE]: true,
    [EnumA.THREE]: true
  }
}

and it would give you an error if you added, say, [EnumA.TWO]: true to mySpecificMapping.  But it's tedious and redundant to write out that EnumA.ONE | EnumA.THREE type argument. It would be nice if TypeScript could just infer that type argument for you, but that's a missing feature requested at microsoft/TypeScript#32794.
If you want generic type argument inference, you need to make a generic function to go with TypeA.  Here's a helper function which serves that purpose:
const typeA = <T extends EnumA>(t: TypeA<T>) => t;

const myObject = typeA({
  myArray: [EnumA.ONE, EnumA.THREE],
  mySpecificMapping: {
    [EnumA.ONE]: true,
    [EnumA.THREE]: true,
  }
});

Now you'll see that myObject is inferred as type TypeA<EnumA.ONE | EnumA.THREE> without you needing to write it out yourself. It's about the same amount of work and keystrokes to write const myObject = typeA({⋯}) instead of const myObject: TypeA = {⋯}, so hopefully it's acceptable.

Anyway, let's make sure you get the behavior you were asking for:
const myObject = typeA({
  myArray: [EnumA.ONE, EnumA.THREE],
  mySpecificMapping: {
    [EnumA.ONE]: true,    
    [EnumA.TWO]: true, // error! 
    [EnumA.THREE]: true,
  }
});

Looks good. You get the error when you add a mySpecificMapping key that isn't present in myArray.
Playground link to code
